# Como evitar cierre del modal

Tags: asp.net

Tengo un modal y dentro tengo un `<asp:button>` y cuando hago click en el button el modal se cierra, como puedo evitar que se cierre mi modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
           <div class="modal fade" id="#myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modalpopup modal-dialog">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                       <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">MI PRIMER MODAL</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" style="height:380px">
                       <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;padding-bottom: 19px;">
                          <div class="column col-md-5">
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">EESS</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="cajared" class="form-control" runat="server" OnTextChanged="cajared_TextChanged" ReadOnly></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="column col-md-7">
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">PROFESIONAL</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="cajaprofe" class="form-control" runat="server" style="width:300px"  OnTextChanged="cajaprofe_TextChanged" ReadOnly></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                        <!--segunfa fila-->
                       <div class="row" style="padding-top:20px">
                          <div class="column col-md-5">
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Enfermedad</label>
                                 <div class="col-md-5">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox32" class="form-control" runat="server">d</asp:TextBox>
                                     </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-3">
                                 <asp:Button class="btn btn-info pull-right" ID="btnBuscaEnfermedad" runat="server" Text="Enfer" />                                         
                                      </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="column col-md-7">
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Paciente</label>
                                 <div class="col-md-10">
                                <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="TextBox33" runat="server">d</asp:TextBox>
                                     </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: que es lo que hace dicho boton: btnBuscaEnfermedad....

Comment: podrias usar esto en javascript: $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})

Comment: Hola @DiegoAvila con el btnBuscaEnfermedad ejecutaré una consulta sql y traeré datos para mostrarlo en el mismo modal, claro esta que le pondre una funcion OnClick=" ". El problema es que se cierra el modal al hacer click